# How to get email from twitter using fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to get email from twitter using fabric, Any one can help me how to get it. I also tried without fabric but it's not worked.

My code is look like below.

```
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

                    session = result.data;

                    String username = session.getUserName();
                    Long userid = session.getUserId();

                    Log.d(":: Name ::", session.getUserName());

                    getUserData();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        void getUserData() {
        Call<User> call = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                .verifyCredentials(true, false);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
                User user = result.data;
                String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

                try {
                    Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl);
                    Log.d("name", user.name);
//                    Log.d("email", user.email);
                    Log.d("des", user.description);
                    Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount));
                    Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt);

                    Log.d("::Name ::", user.name);


                    session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                    TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                    String token = authToken.token;
                    String secret = authToken.secret;
                    authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
                    authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<String> result) {
                            // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
                            Log.d("::::result:::::", result.response + "");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                            // Do something on failure
                        }
                    });


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: sorry to break it to you,but even though we can request twitter for email , irrespective of the method ,its not sure that you will get an email everytime

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
twitauthobj.requestEmail(twitsessionobj,new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<String> stringResult) {
                            'You code here'

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                        }
                    });
```

[image: here is image]

you have to check this addition permission. have you check it ?

Comment: I updated my code I'm using above code but it's showing the dialog of Share your email address with  allow and not now, after allow still not getting email address.

Comment: which permission is here ? in your case https://apps.twitter.com/app/PROJECT_ID/permissions

Comment: Can you describe in briefly, Actually I have no idea about it!

Comment: have you open your account link :apps.twitter.com/app/PROJECT_ID/permissions ?

Comment: Yeah, I opened it and I already gave Read and Write permission and also  checked Request email addresses from users!

Comment: What you are getting in  stringResult.data  inside success method ?

Comment: I can't see result in logcat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129681/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-komal).